# quartz clustering : scheduler actions visible on all nodes

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I'm having an issue; maybe you can help me.

Basically, I would like to know if :

- quartz clustering can have its trigger changed dynamically (i.e. same config on all servers, but at a given point in time, I want to change the cron expression ON A SINGLE SERVER, and see this change propagated on ALL servers).
- generally, if changes on a single server are propagated to all other servers (for example if I stop a particular scheduler on a single node, if all nodes stop the scheduler).

Comment: I am not sure, but I think this depends on what kind of server you use and how you do the clustering?

Comment: "clustering" is a feature bundled with quartz. Job sync is done through database.

Answer (score 2):

1. Unless, you're in for [`TerracottaJobStore`](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/configuration/ConfigTerracottaJobStore), you probably utilize the clustering through database. The way it works is that scheduling data, such as `Trigger`s and `JobDetail`, is saved to the database. All `Scheduler` nodes synchronize on that persisted data. Therefore, a change to that data from one node *is* reflected to all nodes.
2. OTOH, stopping / starting / standby etc. are all management data (as opposed to `Trigger`s and `JobDetail`s). Management data is considered node-specific and does not propagate to other nodes. According to [this](http://markmail.org/message/qn5dibxww3l2yoxf#query%3a+page:1+mid%3avbmjtq2otfswfovu+state%3aresults) post it might in the future...